# Integer won't appear in a TextField

Tags: java, awt

I have a problem with my program. I'm trying to put an integer in a textfield. This is my code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent.*;

public class GradingSystem extends JFrame{

    public GradingSystem(){
        super("Grading System");
        JLabel pre = new JLabel ("PRELIM GRADE: ");
        final JTextField pre1 = new JTextField(10);
        JLabel mid = new JLabel("MIDTERM GRADE: ");
        final JTextField mid1 = new JTextField(10);
        JLabel fin = new JLabel ("FINAL GRADE: ");
        final JTextField fin1 = new JTextField(10);
        JLabel ave = new JLabel("AVERAGE: ");
        final JTextField  ave1 = new JTextField(10);
        JButton calculate = new JButton("CALCULATE");
        FlowLayout flo = new FlowLayout();
        setLayout(flo);
        add(pre);
        add(pre1);
        add(mid);
        add(mid1);
        add(fin);
        add(fin1);
        add(ave);
        add(ave1);
        add(calculate);
        setSize(315,150);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);

        calculate.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                try{
                    int i1 = Integer.parseInt(pre1.getText());
                    int i2 = Integer.parseInt(mid1.getText());
                    int i3 = Integer.parseInt(fin1.getText());
                    int i4 = Integer.parseInt(ave1.getText());

                    i4 = (i1 + i2 + i3) / 3;


                    ave1.setText(String.valueOf(i4));
                }catch(Exception ex){

                }
            }

        });



    }

    public static void main(String[] a){
        GradingSystem gs = new GradingSystem();
    }

}
```

I'm trying have `ave1.setText(String.valueOf(i4));` appear in a textfield but it won't.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Paste in your code, keep it selected and press Ctrl+K, that indents it 4 spaces and shows it in a meaninful way. Always ask direct question, with answers that help you.  (Q: "What will I do guys", A: "Learn a different job than programming"). No distractions, no chit-chat (read [help→tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)), so thanks **never** should be included in a good post.

Comment: Consider using a JSpinner or JFormattedTextField which has the capacity to validate and convert the text to int

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is this line.

```
int i4 = Integer.parseInt(ave1.getText());
```

Presumably, when you click "Calculate", there's no value in `ave1` yet, so this line will throw an exception, and the line below it will never be reached.

Remove that line from your code, and add the word `int` to the line below it.

```
int i4 = (i1 + i2 + i3) / 3;
```

As a general rule, an empty catch block such as the one you're using

```
catch(Exception ex){

}
```

is a REALLY TERRIBLE idea; because it means you don't see what the problem is when an exception is thrown.  Never do this.

Comment: Thank you man. Yeah, i forgot to put `ex.printStackTrace();` man. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 0):

You will see the value in text field only when you click on Calculate button. You are populating that text field only when you click on Calculate button, as you defined action listener on that button.

If you need default value say 10 then you could do something like:

```
 final JTextField  ave1 = new JTextField("10");//or not yet calculated or something on those lines
```

With integer parameter, java doc says:

```
Constructs a new empty <code>TextField</code> with the specified
 * number of columns.
 * A default model is created and the initial string is set to
 * <code>null</code>.
 *
 * @param columns  the number of columns to use to calculate 
 *   the preferred width; if columns is set to zero, the
 *   preferred width will be whatever naturally results from
 *   the component implementation
 */
```

Comment: Yeah. But it won't appear in a textfield.

Comment: Then i would suggest you do `}catch(Exception ex){ ex.printStackTrace();
            }` in your listener as i believe you might not be supplying integer number and you might end up with say NumberFormatException.